# how to use a drawable xml at runtime for a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-styles

I two drawables xml files for a button.
In layout file I set to first xml.
This is my first drawable xml in drawable folder (setup.xml):--

```
<item
    android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="#406934"></solid>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape>
       <corners android:radius="10dp" />
       <solid android:color="#406934"></solid>
    </shape>
</item>
```

I am using it in my layout file as:-

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_actionButton"
    android:text="@string/page_button_action_text"
    -------------
    android:background="@drawable/setup"
    style="@style/action_button" />
```

Now at runtime, I want to change the drawable to another xml(active_button.xml) file based on some condition.

I am using following code, but their is no change.

```
if (item.getTitle().equals("Stop ")) {
    StateListDrawable background = (StateListDrawable) holder.bActionButton.getBackground();
    background.selectDrawable(R.drawable.active_button);
}
```

Any help or pointers!!!

Comment: why not using `Button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_button);` ?

Comment: I wasn't aware about it. Tested and it worked. Thanks. You can add this as answer.

Comment: @indi_mars: Good it's working. same answer is posted please accept which you want.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming @drawable/setup_alert_button and setup.xml are actually the same thing your setup.xml needs an item without and state (android:state_pressed="true" / android:state_focused="true", etc)

That default item should be the last one (the bottom one in the drawable). It will be used as default state and then state_enabled and state_pressed should contain your active drawable. Theres no need to do anything in the code.

If you really need to do it based on title just use

```
holder.bActionButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_button);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it is valuable. I solved it with @ρяσѕρєя K comment and as he said to accept any of the answers, I feel this to be explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy to Sir,ρяσѕρєя K

Please use **matches instead equals**

```
    if (item.getTitle().matches("Stop"))
    {

    StateListDrawable background = (StateListDrawable) holder.bActionButton.getBackground();
    background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_button);
    }
```

Comment: Thank You, Once I have enough votes, the voteup will be visible.I am giving a vote up for your time.

Comment: @indimars As your wish . Happy coding